# Concatenating Python Data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two distinct Python DataFrames (i.e., with a size of 2*2) as follows:

```
Mangoes    Apples
Mangoes    Apples
```

and,

```
1         0
0         1
```

I intend to generate a third DataFrame, so that the output could be:

```
Mangoes       0
0        Apples
```

Obviously, i can't multiply both of these Data Frames (i wish i could have done). So, what should be the best way of doing this? Is this something that can be done by Concatenation? or should i start iterating item-by-item for each DataFrame and store the values into a third DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way may be as following:

```
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
         0       1
0  Mangoes  Apples
1  Mangoes  Apples
```

Other `dataframe`:

```
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  1
```

Then:

```
df_new = (df1*df2).replace('',0)
print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
         0       1
0  Mangoes       0
1        0  Apples
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I have tried using this way, and am getting an error, "TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'".

Comment: @John The possible reason is data type of `df2` is not `integer` or `float` instead it is `string`. So, the error is about trying to multiply two `string`. Can you verify `data type` for `df2` in above example? You can try converting entire `df2` to numeric by `df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric)` and see if `df_new = (df1*df2).replace('',0)` works. To make simple test, you can try running `'mangoes' * 1` and compare to `'mangoes' * '1'`. The later will possibly give same error as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem with data type of d2 ... its resolved. By the way, could you kindly elaborate a bit on this line ... df_new = (df1*df2).replace('   ',0) ... what exactly this ('  ', 0) was doing

Comment: @John if you remove `.replace('',0)` from the line of code, then you will see empty cells i.e. to make simple test you can try: `'mangoes' * 0` will give `''`. So, replacing those empty  cells with `0`. If it resolved your problem, you can accept the answer if you would like. `Happy Coding`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both DFs have the same column names and indexes:

```
In [123]: d1[d2.eq(1)].combine_first(d2)
Out[123]:
         0       1
0  Mangoes       0
1        0  Apples
```

Source DFs:

d1:

```
In [124]: d1
Out[124]:
         0       1
0  Mangoes  Apples
1  Mangoes  Apples
```

d2:

```
In [125]: d2
Out[125]:
   0  1
0  1  0
1  0  1
```